# Pytest BDD - select stubbed or live API calls

Tags: testing, pytest, integration-testing, pytest-mock, pytest-bdd

I'm working on developing some Behavior Driven Development i.e style tests using pytest-bdd.  We want to re-use the same features and more or less the same step definitions to having  both stubbed and live calls to a third party API i.e. we want to reuse test code for integration and end to end testing.

I'm wondering about whether there was a convention on how to handle alternating between mocked and real calls in pytest_bdd or pytest

This question is similar: [Running pytest tests against multiple backends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50678020/running-pytest-tests-against-multiple-backends) with an answer to add a parser option with a `pytest_addoption` hook placed in the top level `conftest.py`.

Comment: What is wrong with the answer you have linked?

Comment: Technically I saw nothing wrong with that approach. However, this was a single answer to the question so I'm still seeking more feedback as to whether this is a preferred style in pytest.

Comment: I'd say yes it is, also the answer comes from a `pytest` dev, a more reliable source is hardly imaginable.

Comment: @joefling thanks for the tip, I hadn't see the author's bio.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a good approach to select a stubbed or live api call in `api` is to add a parser option with a pytest_addoption hook. Conditional logic will need to look for those option in the relevant tests.

This answer to a similar question is the source for this approach and has more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50686439/961659